# PHP block is ignored when using file_get_contents PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to use file_get_contents to load a phtml file and store in variable, but it seems that the php blocks are ignored

```
<?php  include_once '../php_inc/core.inc.php'; ?>
<div class="dialog-header">
    <div class="dialog-header-inner">
        <div class="inline-blk left-align dialog-header-left-item"><div class="bar-title vertical-center">Guitar</div></div>
        <div class="inline-blk right-align dialog-header-right-item pointer">
        <div class="bar-title dialog-header-bar-option inline-blk"><div class="vertical-center" >Post</div></div>
        <div class="bar-title dialog-header-bar-option inline-blk"><div class="vertical-center" ><img src="<?php  echo IMGDIR ?>menu_navi_icon.png" width="20" height="13"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I do something like `echo file_get_contents(myfile.phtml)`, when I inspect the element in the chrome, it automatically comment my php block

```
<!--?php  include_once '../php_inc/core.inc.php'; ?-->
<div class="dialog-header">
    <div class="dialog-header-inner">
        <div class="inline-blk left-align dialog-header-left-item"><div class="bar-title vertical-center">Guitar</div></div>
        <div class="inline-blk right-align dialog-header-right-item pointer">
        <div class="bar-title dialog-header-bar-option inline-blk"><div class="vertical-center">Post</div></div>
        <div class="bar-title dialog-header-bar-option inline-blk"><div class="vertical-center"><img src="<?php  echo IMGDIR ?>menu_navi_icon.png" width="20" height="13"></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the IMGDIR constant didn't get echoed as well.I know I need to use either `GET` OR `POST` to pass custom data. However, I just need to basic set up in the `core.inc.php` like some constant variables,etc.

Comment: I am not sure that your PHP code is commented ... but I think your file is not a `.php` file that is why PHP code is not being executed

Comment: I don't think would be the reason, I usually use `phtml` extension to distinct that the file contains more html codes while with a few lines php codes embedded, but it seems the `file_get_contents` treat it in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) reads the content of a file into a variable. It **does not** interpret the content of the file in any way.

You should [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file instead, if it contains `PHP` code and you want that PHP code to be interpreted.

Another option, when you want to read the file, execute the PHP code it contents but **do not** send the content it generates (HTML code outside the PHP blocks, `echo()`, `print()` etc) immediately to the output but keep it to be used later (or several times) is to use [`output buffering`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
// Start output buffering; it redirects any generated content to a memory buffer
ob_start();
// Include the desired file; this executes the PHP code it contains
// but because of the output buffering, the HTML code is not displayed
// here but buffered
include 'myfile.phtml';
// Get the content of the buffer, clear the buffer, end the buffering
$text = ob_get_clean();
//
// ... more code and/or HTML follows
//
// When you need the content of 'myfile.phtml' you just:
echo($text);
//
// ... more code and/or HTML follows
//
// If you need to display the content of 'myfile.phtml' again you just:
echo($mytext);
```